# Lucene Query for name

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, n-gram

I have a document composed by triples. For example this:

- **George Bush**  |        *lied About by*      |      **Steve**
- **George W. Bush**    |       *lied About by*      |      **Steve**
- **Bush** |   *lied About by* | **Steve**

The first name is the **Subject** the second is the *Verb* and the third is the **Object**. I realizing a Lucene Index composed by three fields (s-v-o) and i want to make queries on subject and object. 
In particular, when i run the query:

**subject:"George Bush" AND object:"Steve"**

I want to retrieve only the first and the third triple, without the triple of George W. Bush.

I tried with NGramsFilter but it doesn't work and it is normal.
How can i filter out the triples that have the subject with some different words? I want to retrieve Bush and so i can't do this:

subject:"+George +Bush" AND object:"+Steve"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for exact matches on the entire contents of a field, you should avoid tokenizing it.  Specifying it as a `StringField` would work, or optionally, you could use a KeywordTokenizer, and apply some filtering to it (`LowercaseFilter`, for instance).

That done, a query like:

```
+subject:("George Bush" George Bush) +object:Steve
```

Would get the results you are looking for.

---

If the difference between "George Bush" and "George W. Bush" is more of a special case you want to handle, you could always work that into the query:

```
+subject:(George Bush -W) +object:Steve
```

You could even work it into a SynonymFilter, I suppose, and during analysis replace instances of "w bush" with "wbush", or something similar.  That would make it impossible to match any document on "george w bush" without the "w" present, which is, I guess, what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for help!! I'm new in Lucene.
I can't search for exact matches because I want to retrieve also the single Bush when i search for "George Bush". 
I was wondering if there is a way to search for "George Bush" and match the field that contains George, Bush, George Bush but nothing else (field that add term at the terms of the query).
Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: The first approach provided above does precisely that, by requiring exact matches, and breaking out the query to enumerate the terms you want to match.